# Codeigniter 5 joins too normalized?

Tags: codeigniter, join, many-to-many

I am building a rather large CodeIgniter application, 
and started off by normalizing the datbase as good as possible.

Let me start that the website is not responding slow or any problems occur.
Just wondering what your opinion is on many joins?

```
$this -> db -> join('A', 'B.user_id = A.id', 'left');
$this -> db -> join('C', 'A.id = C.user_id', 'left');
$this -> db -> join('D', 'B.project_id = D.id', 'left');
$this -> db -> join('E', 'E.client_id = C.id', 'left');
```

As you can see this will call to 5 tables only in the join query.
It is much needed to get every detail of the application data and 3 tables are just linking tables.

Could i have jour honest onion on such joins?

Note: I will need to distinct tables, but i'm waiting on that until everything else is code optimized

Regards,
Chris

Comment: 1. a bit extraneous , but codeigniter is usually used for applications with small footprints (its in the documentation :) )

2. honest opnion on joins , could you elaborate that point , please ?

Comment: Hi, about the honest opions, do you think 4/5 joins on 1 query are much?

Codeigniter could work for larger applications, maybe not ideal indeed :)

Comment: Here's an interesting article on how much normalization is enough.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently in the process of redeveloping a codeigniter application/site. To provide increased flexibility and limit the pulling of redundant data, I have split many single, large tables into multiple small tables. This is resulted in my queries having up to 8 joins on some of my admin queries (not a problem in my opinion for admin queries.)

On the front end many queries have changed from no joins to up to 5 and this has actually increased the speed of the site as I am still pulling less data than I would with the old large table layout.

In short - I dont think there is anything wrong with multiple joins where they serve to reduce the amount of data being pulled, and is really to be expected in any large app.

But this like any other answers you get is an opinion and will all depend on your table structure and the indexes you use more than the number of joins.